# Mapping Western Digital My book World Edition whitelight

Tags: nas, windows-networking

I have a WD Worldbook Whitelight, behind a DDNS configured router, with 443 and 22 ports forwarded.
Share folders on Worldbook are protected with username and password.

While I can access my Worldbook via HTTPS through browser and via SFTP through FileZilla, I am unable to map the Worldbook in Windows (Map Network Drive).

When I type my DDNS name in Windows, nothing happens.

Can someone please tell me what should be the problem?